# Border-top transition doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, border, css-transitions

I'm using the `transition` property in CSS and it doesn't function properly with borders. It transitions in, but not out. Here is my code, any help ?

```css
#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}
#menuitem {
  width: 150px;
  height: 70px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
#menuitem:hover {
  border-top: 12px solid #000;
}
.menutext {
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <div class="menutext" id="menuitem">CONTACT</div>
    <div class="menutext" id="menuitem">ABOUT</div>
    <div class="menutext" id="menuitem">PRICES</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MhkTT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reverse transition will not happen because only on `hover` border is specified. You have to add it to the `#menuitem` also like shown in the snippet to make it transition back to original state.

```css
#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}
#menuitem {
  width: 150px;
  height: 70px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;  /* added this */
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
#menuitem:hover {
  border-top: 12px solid #000;
}
.menutext {
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div class="menutext" id="menuitem">CONTACT</div>
  <div class="menutext" id="menuitem">ABOUT</div>
  <div class="menutext" id="menuitem">PRICES</div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/kN3vn/)

(*Initially I had set `border` property but changed it to match the code in your question.*)

Comment: 23 seconds too slow :(

Comment: @DineshKanivu: Yes, it will because we are transitioning from 0px to 12px top border.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting any `border-top` properties in your non-hover styles. The browser doesn't know what to transition back to, so it just jumps.

Just add this to `#menuitem`:

```
border-top: 0px solid #000
```

(or whatever color you want to transition from, white for no color transition at all)

Answer (score 0):

LIke this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MhkTT/1/)**

**css**

```
#menuitem:hover {
    border-top: none;
}
```

Comment: @Fags: Oops did not notice initially. You have put border as none on `hover`. OP wants the border but it has transition in and out. I am leaving the +1 as-is though (partially because it is now locked :D)

Answer (score 0):

instead of

`border-top: 12px solid #FFF;`

Give this CSS Code

```
box-shadow:inset 0px 12px 0px 0px #000
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MhkTT/2/

Comment: @user2765804 I think it will help you

Comment: If we give border, it will push the element down so Box-shadow:inset id the good Option